# How to save state after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button when I click on it with:

```
this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
```

I render another component, but at the same time my state is saved. But if I reload the page with f5, my state is lost and I can’t load the correct data. Those. the state of the current component depends on another, how can I save this state upon reboot? localstorage does not quite fit

Comment: Use: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started/

Comment: You probably need to call the `api` again in your second component. 

This way you will have your `state`.

You can then use `query` and `params` in your route to filter through the state (that you fetched when you reloaded the page).

Comment: @NicolaeMaties is correct, using something like redux is a great option. Alternatively, mobx, or even graphql can be used for this purpose =]
Alternatively, making use of `sessionstorage` can be an option.

Comment: You will need to use something like the `localStorage` or similar. If you use `redux`, then you can use something like `redux-localstorage`. Otherwise your state is just kept in memory in your `JavaScript` and every time you refresh your page it will be lost.

Comment: @AlexGelinas `redux` by itself will not solve the issue OP is having.

Comment: Thanks all, I can't call API again, it is not API data, I take it from previous component. Redux state is reset after refresh. Does somebody can change redux-localstorage from chrome-inspector etc?